# How to get a proper fill (or alpha) in the legend of a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a graph with observations coming from 4 different setups (2 configurations x 2 type of operations). Now, I would like to have such grouping that same operations share the same shape of symbols, and same configurations have the same fill. Toward that end, I came up with the following code, guided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632242/ggplot-geom-point-how-to-have-filled-and-hollow-shapes-where-the-fill-color?rq=1).

The example:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Stage Config Op.Name Latency Bandwidth
1 0 baseline    read            30.02       33296337
2 0 baseline   write           118.36        8437869
3 0 stuff    read            67.74       14757243
4 0 stuff   write           193.91        5153134
5 20 baseline    read            30.43       32844318
6 20 baseline   write           115.27        8664010
7 20 stuff    read            67.39       14828728
8 20 stuff   write           195.14        5119279
9 40 baseline    read            35.15       28444107
10 40 baseline   write           116.88        8543114
11 40 stuff   read            69.27       14430014
12 40 stuff   write           193.61        5160846", sep = "", header=T)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(Stage), y=Latency, group=interaction(Config, Op.Name), shape=factor(Op.Name))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=factor(Config))) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=factor(Config)), size=6) +
  geom_point(aes(alpha=factor(Config)), size=6) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE, breaks=c('baseline','stuff'), values=c('white', 'black')) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(baseline=0, 'stuff'=1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

This is the outcome: [image: output of the previous program]

What I expect is to see baseline in the legend field with the hollow symbol. 
However, the legend is simply wrong, as both baseline and stuff have a full symbol. What should I do to have a baseline presented as a hollow symbol in the legend, or how should I invoke ggplot to have the graph as I want?

I'm running R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25), with ggplot2 version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this problem, I managed to solve it by adding:

```
 guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22)))
```

to the mix.

The final code is (notice the removal of factor and the alpha layer):

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Stage, y=Latency, group=interaction(Config, Op.Name), shape=Op.Name)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Config)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=Config), size=6) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24)) +
  scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE, breaks=c('baseline','stuff'), values=c('white', 'black')) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 22))) +
  theme_bw()
```

Which produced the following result:
[image]

I got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488905/why-wont-the-ggplot2-legend-combine-manual-fill-and-scale-values?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the legend for the fill uses filled circles. So you can only change the color using the `color` argument, not the `fill` argument. This works fine if you use any color other than `white`. Below is my solution. I realize that that's not exactly what you were looking for.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(Stage), 
                     y=Latency, 
                     group=interaction(Config, Op.Name), 
                     shape=factor(Op.Name))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=factor(Config))) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=factor(Config), color=factor(Config), alpha=factor(Config)), size=6) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19,17)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray30', 'black')) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('gray30', 'black')) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c('baseline'=0.5, 'stuff'=1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Alternatively, you can put both `Config` and `Op.Name` into the `shape` argument and use the appropriate shapes. Perhaps that is closer to what you were looking for.

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(Stage), 
                     y=Latency, 
                     shape=interaction(Config, Op.Name), 
                     group=interaction(Config, Op.Name))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=factor(Config))) +
  geom_point(size=6) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("baseline.read" = 1, 
                              "stuff.read" = 16, 
                              "baseline.write" = 2, 
                              "stuff.write" = 17), 
                     labels = c('Baseline reading', 'Stuff reading', 
                                'Baseline writing', 'Stuff writing')) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(guide='none') +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thanks @shadow, the second proposal seems quite readable and elegant.