# Removing stat_summary symbols from legend categories in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I have the following code that has created two violin plots:

```
ggplot(both,aes(x=levelsname,y=loginc,fill=levelsname))+
geom_violin() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,
               aes(shape="Mean"),
               colour='black',
               geom="point",
               size=3)+
    scale_shape_manual("Summary Statistics", values=c("Mean"="+"))+  
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray70','orange','red'))+
  scale_x_discrete(name="Site Category")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Log(Incidence/100,000")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "Site Category"))+
  facet_grid(~ANA)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

[image: Violin plot]

Everything is correct for these plots apart from the legend. I am attempting to remove the black circles from the legend under site category and replace them with the + symbol. I also would like to move the + and mean legend symbol underneath the site category legend items, such that it looks like one legend.

Comment: Add `show.legend = FALSE` to the stat call

Comment: Likely a dupe. [Remove legend ggplot 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618260/remove-legend-ggplot-2-2)

Comment: @camille Adding show.legend=FALSE removes the circle inside the site category legend, but also removes the Mean from the legend.

Comment: Oh, got it. You can use `override.aes` for a specific legend type, in this case the fill legend. Seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11417517/5325862) post should have you covered, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29941900/5325862) one might help as well

Comment: @Tjebo they don't want to remove any entire legends, which is what that post is about

Comment: @camille fair. Was just a two second google because this is most likely a dupe. may not be the best choice though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have `shape="Mean"` within the `aes` call.  It is not an aesthetic mapping!  Having it in the `aes` makes `ggplot` think you are setting `shape` to be mapped to a character variable that always takes the value `"mean"`.  Hence the weird legend.

You can just use `shape="+"` as an argument in the `stat_summary` call to get the effect you want.  You'll probably have to take out the `scale_shape_manual("Summary Statistics", values=c("Mean"="+"))` line as well, because there is no longer a shape scale.

To answer the last part of your question, if you want to have a separate "mean" line for your legend you *can* add an extra level "Mean" to the variable mapped to the `fill` aesthetic (then manually set its fill to transparent).  See below:

```
d <- data.frame(x=factor(c(1,2)), y=rnorm(100))

ggplot(d, aes(x,y, group=x, fill=x)) + 
   geom_violin() + 
   stat_summary(shape="+", fun="mean", aes(fill="Mean"), geom="point", size=3) +
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red", "#00000000"), limits=c(1,2,"Mean"))
```

[image]

**Edit:**  I found a way to get rid of the box around the + in the Mean line of the legend but it's a horrible hack.  You need two `stat_summary` layers, one with `color` set to transparent with an aesthetic mapping (so that the legend box is transparent, but this makes the legend "+" transparent also) and then second with `color="black"` directly which replaces the "+" in the legend but not the box.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x,y, group=x, fill=x, color=x)) + 
   geom_violin() + 
   stat_summary(shape="+", fun="mean", aes(fill="Mean",color="Mean"), geom="point", size=3)+
   stat_summary(shape="+", fun="mean",color="black", geom="point", size=3) +
   theme_classic() + 
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightblue", "red", "#00000000"), limits=c(1,2,"Mean"))+  
   scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "black", "#00000000"), limits=c(1,2,"Mean"))
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, the only problem I am having is that my legend is automatically ordered alphabetically, causing "Mean" to be put in the center of my legend and throwing off the color scales.

Comment: @coconn41 apologies I didn't think of that..  you'll have to set the order levels in the `scale_fill_manual` layer.  I will update my answer..

Comment: @coconn41 I have edited, if Mean isn't alphabetically last then you need to set the order of the levels in the `limits()` option for each scale.